# Getting Project Version from Node / package.json in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins

How do we get project version from package.json from a node project in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Jenkinsfile to get the Project Version from package.json

```yaml
stage('Read JSON') {
         steps {
             script {
            def packageJSON = readJSON file: 'package.json'
            def packageJSONVersion = packageJSON.version
            echo "${packageJSONVersion}"
         }
         }
      }
```

For more reference: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace